# How to read image tag from RSS itunes

Tags: php, xml, rss

I try to read my iTunes RSS. I can read title, even itunes:subtitle but I have problems with the tag image.

FEED:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">

<channel>
<title>title of the podcast</title>  
<itunes:image href="http://www.MyWeb/myImg.png"/>
</channel>
</rss>
```

PHP:

```
$xml=("http://www.myWeb/rss.xml");
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);

$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')//normal tag
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$channel_image = $channel->getElementsByTagName('image') //problem
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $channel_title . '<br>';
echo $channel_image . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use SimpleXML. Because the `image` element has a namespace prefix (`itunes`), you have to use the children method to pass the namespace URL, then call the `attributes` method:

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://www.myWeb/rss.xml');
foreach ($feed->channel as $channel) {
  $ns_itunes = $channel->children('http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd');
  echo $ns_itunes->image->attributes();
}
```

Comment: What does $ns_itunes exactly does? I have paste the address in Safary and I cannot see anything

Comment: I tried the snippet above (of course with a correct path to the .xml) and it works just fine. With `$ns_itunes` you can easily call every tag with `itunes:` in front of it now, because you declared what namespace to use.

Comment: Yes, the code works but I do not understand what does the $ns_itunes does or what is in the iTunes address.

Comment: The children function gets all the elements children: http://php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.children.php . The address given as paramter simply states the namespace. You can also remove it, if that's whats irritating you.

Comment: You can't simply remove the namespace declaration. You can think of a xml namespace kind of like an area code in telephone numbers. For more information just have a look at some google results to `xml namespace`.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute `xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"` defines an alias/prefix itunes for the a namespace.

The DOM resolves that to the namespace prefix, so you can read the image node name as:

```
{http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd}:image
```

You're currently using the standard DOM function to fetch nodes. Here are namespace aware versions of them (suffix NS). But a better solution is Xpath. This is part of the DOM extension and allows you to use expression to fetch data from a DOM.

Create an DOMXPath instance  for your DOM and fetch the title as string:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($xmlDoc);

echo $xpath->evaluate('string(/rss/channel/title)'), "\n";
```

To address nodes in a namespace you need to register your own prefix for it.

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($xmlDoc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('it', 'http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd');

echo $xpath->evaluate('string(/rss/channel/it:image/@href)');
```

Here can be several items so fetch and iterate them, use the returned node as the context argument in evaluate to get details.

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/rss/channel/item') as $item) {
  echo $xpath->evaluate('string(enclosure/@url)', $item);
}
```

Comment: It works well too. I only have problems with the tag url that is inside item:<enclosure url="http://www.myWeb/mySound.mp3" length="624557" type="audio/mp3"/> I tried: $xpath->evaluate('string(/rss/channel/item/enclousure/@url)');

Comment: You have a typo in the word `enclosure` in the expression. I added a an example for the items.

Comment: I tried to search to learn more about this method and I found that evaluate does not work with IExplorer, did I understand well? Is this a good place to learn more? http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp

Comment: Yes and no. IE has no implementation of the DOM3 Xpath spec, but it can be added with a JS library.