# PHP parse XML within XML

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file that contains XML within it. How would I go about parsing everything into an array or object?

```
<DATA>
    <ROW>
        <id>1</id>
        <message_id>123456789</message_id>
        <brand_name>SAMPLE</brand_name>
        <request_xml>
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
&lt;Email&gt;
&lt;Service&gt;
&lt;LogMessage/&gt;
&lt;Delivery&gt;
&lt;Synchronous/&gt;
&lt;/Delivery&gt;
&lt;/Service&gt;
&lt;Model&gt;
&lt;Head&gt;
&lt;From&gt;someone@example.com &lt;/From&gt;
&lt;To&gt;someone@sample.com&lt;/To&gt;
&lt;Subject&gt;Your Question&lt;/Subject&gt;
&lt;/Head&gt;
&lt;ns2:ContactUs&gt;
&lt;ns2:Sender&gt;
&lt;ns2:FirstName&gt;John&lt;/ns2:FirstName&gt;
&lt;/ns2:Sender&gt;
&lt;/ns2:ContactUs&gt;
&lt;/Model&gt;
&lt;InlineImages/&gt;
&lt;History/&gt;
&lt;/Email&gt;
        </request_xml>
        <http_status>400</http_status>
        <created_by>admin</created_by>
        <created_on>2014-09-08 01:56:59</created_on>
    </ROW>
</DATA>
```

My goal is to end up with somthing like that:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [ROW] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [message_id] => 123456789
            [brand_name] => SAMPLE
            [request_xml] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    ...
                    [LogMessage] => 
                    ...
                    [from] => someone@example.com
                    ...
                )

            [http_status] => 400
            [created_by] => admin
            [created_on] => 2014-09-08 01:56:59
        )
)
```

I didn't put all levels of the `request_xml` in my example, but you get the idea. Basically I want that `request_xml` to be parsed like the rest of the XML file.

How could I achieve this? Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Comment: Why not just parse main string in SimpleXML, extract substring, parse that as SimpleXML and add sub XML as node to main XML?

Comment: How would I deal with the encoding?

Comment: You could either use `html_entity_decode` or `str_replace` with a specific set of entities.

Comment: To deal with the encoding, I ended up using `simplexml_load_string($xmlfile, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOENT);` so I didn't need to use `html_entity_decode`.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the node value of `request_xml` element node, the result will have the entities decoded.

```
$outer = new DOMDocument();
$outer->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($outer);

$innerXml = $xpath->evaluate('string(/DATA/ROW/request_xml)');
echo $innerXml;
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Email>
<Service>
<LogMessage/>
...
```

You can load the inner xml into a separate document object.

```
$inner = new DOMDocument();
$inner->loadXml(trim($innerXml));
echo $inner->saveXml();
```

But in your example the inner XML is broken. It is missing the namespace definition for the ns2 prefix. If added it will work:

Demo: https://eval.in/191279

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have omitted the namespace definition in my question but it actually is there. But for some reason, `simplexml_load_string()` fails to parse these ns2 tags. But that is not a big issue. What I really care is the content of the fields, so I can do a quick `str_replace` on the tags before parsing.

Comment: SimpleXMLs namespace handling is a little complex, you can register your own prefixes using SimpleXMLElement::registerXpathNamespace() and use them with xpath(), some of the methods are namespace aware, too. But it is only valid for a that element, on a child element your have to register them again. DOM uses a separate object for Xpath so you have to register them only once. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25571382/2265374